# Spring PropertySource based on environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to use a dynamic placeholder inside the `PropertySource` value options.

This is in order to have the ability to have one file for each environment which overrides the default one. Just like `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties`.

Current setup:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:ione.properties")
```

I would like to have something like

```
@PropertySource("classpath:ione-{optionalEnvName}.properties")
```

Thus reading the `--spring.profiles.active=dev` option.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't show how to use a dynamic variable inside the PropertySource annotation. The @Profile annotation would require multiple classes for each property file. Which would clutter the consumer (who doesn't care which one).

Comment: check this link :http://greendotsoftware.co.uk/?tag=propertysource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

and then:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:ione-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

should work

Comment: Thanks. That works indeed. Sadly it's not exactly how spring handles the `application.properties` file. I can't have a file: `ione.properties` and ione-`dev.properties` basically. If I don't provide the `spring.profiles.active` argument, spring will complain it can't find ` ione-.properties` for example.

Comment: `@PropertySource(value = {
        "classpath:properties/ione.properties",
        "classpath:properties/ione-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
})`
This for example will complain that the file `ione-.properties` does not exist when running the app without any profile set.

Comment: @NicolasWidart There's a cure for that - just use:
`@PropertySource("classpath:ione-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)`

Comment: @NicolasWidart Another possibility is to define default values: @PropertySource("classpath:ione-${spring.profiles.active:default}.properties")